# ¿Cómo solucionar el campo ID de tipo identity para que se genere correctamente de 1 en 1?

Tags: sql, server, identity, id

**Hola a todos, quisiera saber por que el ID de mi tabla productos de tipo identity cambia y como solucionar para que se genere correctamente de 1 en 1.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Como se puede ver en la imagen de repente se inserta de esa forma.**

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! cual es la necesidad de que se ejecute de 1 en 1? supongo que esto es sql server? identity no asegura al 100% que no haya agujeros.. si lo necesitas sin agujeros tenes que hacer tu propio mecanismo

Comment: hola amig@ bienvenid@ a stackoverflow te recomiendo que te leas este articulo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Saludos. y edites tu pregunta.

Comment: en modo diseño de tu tabla selecciona el ID que quieres y en las opciones que te aparecen abajo busca el que dice identity especification y seleccionas Identity increment ahi lo puedes poner de cuanto quiers que incremente.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15 lean ahi.. eso no asegura que no haya agujeros...

Comment: Además, ahí no sabemos que ha pasado. Puede ser que se borraran parte de los datos, y el id pues seguirá incrementando en el último que se borró...

Comment: No sólo **NO** se asegura que el identity sea consecutivo, sino que **no deberías crear código que dependa del Identity Key**. Suena contra intuitivo, pero tu llave primaria no necesariamente es el identity. La llave primaria es una columna (o combinación de columnas) que **identifica al objeto de manera única**. El **código de producto**, por ejemplo, es único e identifica completamente al producto. **ESA** es la llave primaria. No dependas siempre del Identity.

Answer (score 5):

**Nada asegura que** los valores de identity **se creen consecutivamente**. La documentación menciona muy claramente que los números generados con una columna con especificación de identidad, no tienen porque ser correlativos.

Como bien dice @gbianchi, y aunque la opción NOCACHE a la hora de generar este tipo de valores, puede ayudar (con un peor rendimiento) al mismo, eso no hace que sean únicos, correlativos, ni sin saltos.

[Deshabilitar cache Identity](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-scoped-configuration-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
Create table dbo.TestId (
id int identity(1,1) primary key,  -- garantiza la unicidad,
col1 int
)
go
Insert into dbo.TestId
(col1)
values(1);
go
Set transaction isolation level serializable
BEGIN TRY
    begin tran

    Insert into dbo.TestId
    (col1) 
    values (2);
    
    Declare @num int = 0;
    select 1/@num; 
    COMMIT TRAN;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN; -- 
END CATCH
GO
    Insert into dbo.TestId
    (col1) 
    values (2);
GO
    Select * from dbo.TestId
```

[image: Resultado]

El resultado final, es que existen diferentes factores que se pueden dar, además del reinicio del servidor, para que identity no sea consecutivo. Esto no se garantiza.

[Identity Verdades y mentiras](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/27/identity-o-autonumerico-verdades-y-mentiras/)

Las secuencias, adolecen del mismo problema.

Puedes garantizar la consecutividad de los registros de otras maneras.

Te dejo un enlace.

[ids incrementales ¿Cómo?](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/23/id-incremental-como/)