# Problemas de insercion JAVA - SQL

Tags: java, sql-server, insert, jdbc, identity

tengo un problema, cuando realice mis pruebas en la inserción de registros  no tenia ningún problema pero ya mas de 1 mes después de ponerlo en producción  me percato que de vez en cuando la llave primaria no respeta el identity que le puse.

Mi llave primaria es [idTurno] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se muestra el campo "idturno" no esta respetando su correlativo, en vez de seguir con el "90" se pasa al 91,el usuario no tiene forma de eliminar registros en el sistema, esto me ha pasado en 2 oportunidades en el ultimo mes, la verdad no se que podria estar pasando, revise el código en java pero es un insert muy simple para tener errores :

```
 private static java.sql.Date getCurrentDate() {
            java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
            return new java.sql.Date(today.getTime());
        }
       public String CrearTurnos(String Fecha,String tipo, String idUsuario,String tmh,String flujometro,String humedad,String leyCabeza,String leySolRica,String leySolBarren,String leySolRelave)throws SQLException{
            Connection con = Coneccion.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
            ps.setString(1, Fecha);
            ps.setString(2, tipo);
            ps.setString(3, idUsuario);
            ps.setString(4, "Pendiente");
            ps.setDate(5, getCurrentDate());
            ps.setString(6, tmh);
            ps.setString(7, flujometro);
            ps.setString(8, humedad);
            ps.setString(9, leyCabeza);
            ps.setString(10, leySolRica);
            ps.setString(11, leySolBarren);
            ps.setString(12, leySolRelave);
            if(ps.executeUpdate()==1){
                ps.close();
                    con.close();
                        }
                return "Creacion Exitosa";
        }
```

Cualquier información o ayuda es bienvenido, Gracias de ante mano!

Comment: Es probable que haya habido un intento de inserción fallido en algún punto, en esos casos el auto incremental aumenta, aunque la inserción no ocurra. Para evitar eso podrías verificar si el registro existe antes de intentar una inserción.

Comment: En esta otra pregunta se aborda el tema y tienes posibles soluciones, pero la especificación de identidad no garantiza nunca valores consecutivos. Da igual que utilices no cache o cualquier otra técnica. [Identity genera saltos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/384383/c%c3%b3mo-solucionar-el-campo-id-de-tipo-identity-para-que-se-genere-correctamente-d/384391#384391)