# ERROR EN IDENTITY SQL SERVER 2017

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, id

Buenas noches Compañeros Tengo un problema en una inserción de datos en SQL Server .
Tengo mi tabla de Departamentos pero al principio agrega bien los datos 1 , 2 , 3 pero después me arroja 1001, 1002, 1003 así sucesivamente.  De echo en todas mis tablas así siempre del ID 3 en adelante se cambia a 1001 etc.

Este es mi código de la tabla

```
Create table Departamentos
(id int Identity(1,1) primary key, Nombre varchar(50));
```

Realmente no sé porque sé cambia de esa manera , si en cada registro de debe de ir incrementando uno a uno.
Espero de puedan colaborar en eso.
Gracias

Comment: No es un error de SQL Server 2017 ni de identity. La documentación oficial no garantiza los saltos. Mira esta respuesta, para tú mismo problema 
 [¿Como solucionar para que el identity se genere correctamente de 1 en 1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/384383/c%c3%b3mo-solucionar-el-campo-id-de-tipo-identity-para-que-se-genere-correctamente-d/384391#384391). Puedes usar la opción noCache, pero ni eso te garantiza los saltos.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo solucionar el campo ID de tipo identity para que se genere correctamente de 1 en 1?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/384383/c%c3%b3mo-solucionar-el-campo-id-de-tipo-identity-para-que-se-genere-correctamente-d)